# How to add values of two fields and show it into third with Jquery

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am creating a order form. Price will be calculated for each product based on quantity. This calculation is working. Once the customer selects the quantity for products. Total No. Items and Total Price must show up. I am not able to do calculation for addition. Can somebody help? Below is the code and screenshot.

[image]

```
    <div class="pp">
<h3>Choose From Range of Premium Breads</h3>
Product 1
<br><br>
<input type="text" name="text-695" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" id="qty" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Enter QTY">
<input type="text" name="text-792" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text tp" id="price" aria-invalid="false">
<br><br>
Product 2
<br><br>
<input type="text" name="text-696" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" id="qty1" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Enter QTY">
<input type="text" name="text-793" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text tp" id="price1" aria-invalid="false">

<br><br>Total Price<br><br>
<input type="text" name="text-903" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" id="items" aria-invalid="false">
<input type="text" name="text-362" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" id="total" aria-invalid="false">
</div>


jQuery(document).ready(function(){
//alert("Welcome");
var qty;
var price;
var qty1;
var price1;
var x;
var total;

jQuery("#qty").on("change", function() {
 qty= this.value ;
 price=qty*8.50;
jQuery("#price").val(price.toFixed());

}); 
jQuery("#qty1").on("change", function() {
 qty1= this.value ;
 price1=qty1*9.50;
jQuery("#price1").val(price1.toFixed());

});

jQuery("#price").on("change", function() {
 x= this.value ;
 total=x;
jQuery("#total").val(total.toFixed());

});

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to show the sum of prices for the 2 items in the #total input box, then you can probably do something like below.

You should keep the code that updates the total in a separate function and then invoke that function whenever any of the 2 item's quantity is changed.

```js
//alert("Welcome");
var qty;
var price;
var qty1;
var price1;
var x;
var total;

jQuery("#qty").on("change", function() {
 qty= this.value ;
 price=qty*8.50;
jQuery("#price").val(price.toFixed());
 updateTotal();

}); 
jQuery("#qty1").on("change", function() {
 qty1= this.value ;
 price1=qty1*9.50;
jQuery("#price1").val(price1.toFixed());
 updateTotal();

});

function updateTotal(){
  //  calculate price total
  var priceofItem1 = parseFloat( price ) || 0;
  var priceofItem2 = parseFloat( price1 ) || 0;
  var total = priceofItem1 + priceofItem2;
  
  // calculate items total
  var quantityofItem1 = parseFloat( qty ) || 0;
  var quantityofItem2 = parseFloat( qty1 ) || 0;
  var totalQuantity = quantityofItem1 + quantityofItem2;
  
  jQuery("#items").val( totalQuantity );
  jQuery("#total").val( total );  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pp">
<h3>Choose From Range of Premium Breads</h3>
Product 1
<br><br>
<input type="text" name="text-695" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" id="qty" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Enter QTY">
<input type="text" name="text-792" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text tp" id="price" aria-invalid="false">
<br><br>
Product 2
<br><br>
<input type="text" name="text-696" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" id="qty1" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Enter QTY">
<input type="text" name="text-793" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text tp" id="price1" aria-invalid="false">

<br><br>Total Price<br><br>
<input type="text" name="text-903" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" id="items" aria-invalid="false">
<input type="text" name="text-362" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" id="total" aria-invalid="false">
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for help. I need a sum of items too. Also the field should not be mandatory. Customer should be able to enter for just 1 product as well. Can you help me in that too?

Comment: I have updated the answer to update sum of quantities also. Please check.

Comment: Thanks Robin. But again price fields for both products are mandatory. It don't show the total with price for just product 1.

Comment: Also, this code works well in fiddle but not working on my website.

Comment: I have fixed the mandatory thing. Can you just tell me how do I make it work on my website? It's not working there.

Comment: I have also updated the code to make a few additional fixes. For your website I need to know the link.

Comment: There is an error on your page related to datepicker. Can you please fix this error first? `Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).datepicker is not a function`

Comment: @SargamGupta please wrap the code from this answer in a `document ready` block. I had not added that code here in the answer because SO takes care of it. But when using it you need to add that.

Comment: It worked. Thanks. Just 1 last thing please. See the screenshot. Again the both the price fields are mandatory. Check https://prnt.sc/hgavs3 I tried assigning 0 default value. But it didn't work.

Comment: Please use the updated code from the answer above. Initially there was a typo in `updateTotal()` function in my code that you have used on your page. Also, I have added `parseFloat()` calls. Use the updated code and it should work fine.